# Error in Apache NiFi ExecuteSQL Processor: org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["null","long"]

Tags: sql, avro, apache-nifi, hdf

[image: UnresolvedUnionException for id that are of type BIGINT UNSIGNED INT]

Table Schema: 
id BIGINT(20), UNSIGNED INT, AUTOINCREMENT
account_id INT(64), UNSIGNED INT, CAN BE NULL

Was anyone able to solve this error?
I'm using Apache NiFi 0.7.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in the way NiFi handles BigInteger objects with respect to Avro, I have written it up in Apache Jira:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2531

If possible to redefine your column types, you may be able to pick a type that will fit in a "long" object under the hood, such as INT(19) in MySQL or something like that.